# Select box fullscreen jquery bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, select

I have found a full screen selextbox method for mobile phones.

http://craftpip.github.io/bootstrap-fullscreen-select/

But when i'm add a form action on the select box and click on a select option the popups open and before i choose some value it redirects directly to the form action.

Any idea how i can solve this?

```
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Mobile-First-Fullscreen-Select-Replacement-with-jQuery-Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-fullscreen-select.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<form action="index.html">
    <select class="form-control example-1" >
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Swift">Swift</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
</select>

  </form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Mobile-First-Fullscreen-Select-Replacement-with-jQuery-Bootstrap/js/bootstrap-fullscreen-select.js"></script>
<script>
$('.example-1').mobileSelect();
$('.example-2').mobileSelect({theme: 'holo',style: 'btn-danger'});
$('.example-3').mobileSelect({theme: 'mac', animation: 'zoom'});
</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest posting your code implementation of this, html and js

Comment: i have added the code that i use.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4a631pkk/10/ also a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, I have never used this plugin, so I had to dig around the source a bit.  Anyways, your native selects are being converted into buttons.  Buttons in forms will submit.  Add this snippet to your own js file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-mobileSelect-gen').attr('type', 'button');
});
```

I forked your fiddle here - [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k93wdxus/)